# Даты в календаре

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

помогите пожалуйста! никак не могу сделать вот что:
у меня есть два календаря. в первом минимальная дата - сегодняшняя. дальше пользователь выбирает любой день. а во втором нужно поставить минимальной датой ту, которую пользователь выбрал в первом календаре. буду благодарна, если скажите как это сделать

```js
var now = new Date();
var today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + parseInt(now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
$(function() {
  $('.thisday').prop('min', function() {
    return new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('.backDay').prop('min', function() {
    return //здесь должно быть то,чего я не знаю;
  });
});
```

```html
<input class="thisday" placeholder="date" type="date" id="min" max="2016-12-31">
<input class="backDay" placeholder="date" type="hidden" id="min" max="2016-12-31">
```

Comment: код в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: @Blacknife я уже добавила

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

У каждого тега должен быть свой уникальный `id`, а у вас у двух тегов `input`, один `id` на двоих.

```js
var userCal=document.getElementById("min");
var shadowCal=document.getElementById("max");
userCal.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  shadowCal.min=e.currentTarget.value;
  alert("Урра!!! Теперь атрибут min,тега input, класса backDay равен "+shadowCal.min);
},false);
```

```html
<input class="thisday" placeholder="date" type="date" id="min" max="2016-12-31"/>
<input class="backDay" placeholder="date" type="date" id="max" max="2016-12-31"/>
```

Comment: Ну и думаю стоит добавить, что некоторые браузеры (Mozilla Firefox, Safary, IE...) ещё не наверстали все возможности html5 и в них `type="date"` работать не будет, по-этому стоит обратить внимание на альтернативное решение в виде скрипта, к примеру: [jQueryUI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: я привел демонстрационный код,  с jquery у меня как-то не сложилось

Comment: @Otis666 спасибо огромное за помощь!